# Is there a way to disable scrolling to the Spy-disguise & Engineer Build/Demolish menus?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy, tf2-engineer

With most other classes I can quickly switch between weapons easily with the scroll-wheel (with the option to Auto-switch instead of menu-switch turned on), and this is quite helpful.

However, when I'm bringing up the Spy's Disguise menu (or the engineer's build/demolish menus) I'll press the keybind to bring up the menu, as I then need to press another key to select the disguise/building.

However, I can also scroll on the wheel into these menus, which is *never* what I intended to do. I always just want to switch from the wrench to, say the pistol or the shotgun, or the sapper to the knife.

So, is there any way to disable those menus from appearing when scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this. However, I have an alternate control scheme which you might find worth trying.

I don't find single-stepping a scroll wheel a reliable input method, so I have rebound my wheel to function simply as switching buttons:

```
bind "MWHEELUP" "slot3"
bind "MWHEELDOWN" "slot1"
bind "MOUSE4" "slot2"
bind "MOUSE5" "slot4"
```

I've also bound <kbd>Q</kbd> to be an 'absolute' switch key rather than the default last-weapon function:

```
bind "q" "slot10; slot3"
```

The `slot10` causes it to continue to function as the cancel key for spy/engineer menus. If you don't have a fourth mouse button (as I do) and don't want to use wheel-press as a switch key (as I don't), then you could bind <kbd>Q</kbd> to the slot that wheel up/down aren't bound to.

Comment: Stealing [my old answers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82428/how-do-i-ensure-a-successful-degreaser-axtinguisher-combo/82441#82441), huh?  I see how it is. :]

Comment: @SteveV. Well, according to [my answer there](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82428/how-do-i-ensure-a-successful-degreaser-axtinguisher-combo/82448#82448), I invented it independently...

Comment: Just had a go with these alternate controls. Not bad, although will take a bit of getting used to. thanks +1